# Direct DB connection shows all records, C#/ASP dropping a single record

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

When I run a query from SQLDeveloper it runs fine and retrieves all records.  The code below is retrieving all but one record when a department is asking about.  Is there caching of sorts of queries that a newly created entry would not show? I am using the Oracle DataAccess client and not the deprecated one.

Code:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
string currentDatabase = universalDll.getDB();
        List<string> majors = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[currentDatabase].ConnectionString;



            conn.Open();

            string sql =
                "SELECT DISTINCT description,code " +
                "FROM tablea a " +
                "JOIN tableb b " +
                "ON a.code = b.code ";


            sql += "ORDER BY b.description";


            OracleCommand executeQuery = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            executeQuery.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataReader dr = executeQuery.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ddlChooser.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr.GetString(0) + "(" + dr.GetString(1) + ")", dr.GetString(1)));
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same query in the C# code and in the SQLDeveloper ? when you run it in SQLDeveloper is it on the same session as the insert of the new record ?

Comment: Here was the problem: Oracle SQL Developer sometimes requires you to commit changes before other users can see them in the database. Although I could see my changes as logged in, the IIS server could not. Once I commited changes it worked fine.

Comment: Oracle DB **always** requires a commit before it can be seen in another session, this is why I asked you if it's in the same session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem: Oracle SQL Developer sometimes requires you to commit changes before other users can see them in the database. Although I could see my changes as logged in, the IIS server could not.  Once I commited changes it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the fine print that an OracleDataReader starts before the first record so Read() advances to the first record on a newly opened dataset.

I'll revise my statement in that your final Read() is returning false and not being added to your chooser.

Comment: But OP isn't re-reading inside the while loop. More than that, I would expect it to read the first record twice in your solution.